# jQuery datepicker wouldn't scroll between months and nothing happens when it closes in IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to make the sample from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) work on my page. I've included the following into my page body:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>

<div id="myDivId">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div>
```

which is the same as the sample.

In the sample when I click onto the edit box the datepicker appears. I can step between months and when I click on a specific date that date gets posted into the edit box.

Now on my page when I click onto the edit box the datepicker does appear, but "next" and "previous" buttons have no effect and when I click onto a specific date the datepicker doesn't close and the date is not posted but the page scrolls to the top.

The problem is only reproduced in IE (I tried IE 8 only) - works in both Firefox and Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check for javascript errors? What versions of the files are you using?

Comment: How about a link to your page or a jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: @Tim B James: I don't see any error messages in IE debugging console. The files are version 1.8.7.

Comment: @sharptooth Could you maybe go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and put your code in there? Give us something to test and see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because of some "extra safe" configuration that is enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2 by default.